# Inno Setup: a shortcut to program's folder in Start menu

Tags: inno-setup

I have added several items into my program's folder in Start menu (using [Icons] section)
Now I would like to add a shortcut to that folder on desktop.
I've tried the following rule:

```
[Icons]
Name: {userdesktop}\My Program Folder; Filename: {group}; WorkingDir:{group};
```

but this rule creates a short of "File" type instead of "File folder" type.

Is it possible to add the same shortcut but with "File folder" type?

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're asking. Your current `[Icons]` entry creates a shortcut to the folder specified by the `{group}` constant, which is quite useless, since that is a path to the Start Menu folder. To make a shortcut for a file you usually use `{app}\MyApp.exe` for the `Filename` parameter.

Comment: I need exactly what I asked about: a shortcut to my Start Menu folder placed on desktop.
I don't need a shortcut to the exe file.

Comment: If you are asking why I need this - it's for Windows 8 systems where users don't have access to Start Menu folders of installed programs from their desktops.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, what you have should work, or actually works on Windows 7. I'll check that in Windows 8.1, but it's at least weird that the `{group}` would return "a file" instead of folder...

Comment: On Windows 8.1 I can reproduce it, so the OS version is crucial for your question... Even though the Inno Setup creates a shortcut with a proper target, the shortcut type is wrong. My first guess is the problem is with [`this workaround`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Install.pas#L1774) which might not apply to Windows 8... In all cases, this is a bug.

Comment: The problem seems to be with something else. I've tried to extract the `CreateShellLink` function and call it explicitly with the `FolderShortcut` parameter set to False and it worked as expected. On my Windows 8.1 testing machine a folder shortcut has been created. From Inno Setup on the same system it failed with your script entry. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

You can use`Flags: foldershortcut` in `[Icons]` section to create a shortcut of a folder.